# WCF - pass user credentials without secure communication

Tags: .net, wcf, authorization, credentials

Is there a way to pass user credentials over a WCF service without using secure communication?

(they are not transmitted when using insecure communication)

I want to avoid doing it manually, because it would affect every service method...

Background: this is for a system which runs in a closed environment, but requires role-based decisions

Comment: Why not use a secure connection?

Comment: In order to improve performance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WCF **by design** prohibits use of clear-text username/password.

You may use *Message Security* with X509 certificates for encryption or use a *Secured transport* (e.g. HTTPS) to pass credentials. **Performance of Transport security is better so that is what I would recommend.**

This was possible under WSE (although advised against) but not in WCF.

Comment: Thank you! The system runs in a secure environment, so we want to use insecure communication - however, we need a role-based decision system...

Answer (score 0):

I just found another possible solution: implement your own binding which supports clear-text username/password

See here:

http://code.google.com/p/wcf-clear-username-binding/

However, I am not yet sure about the pros & cons of this solution...